Error in Ninjatrader indicator Script editor
I was trying to create an indicator ninja trader based on Donchian channel but it shows more than 30 errors of The value is not in the context. so is it better to code in VS studion not in ninjatrader script editor.
here's the code-
#region Using declarations
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using NinjaTrader.Data;
using NinjaTrader.NinjaScript;
using NinjaTrader.Gui.Tools;
#endregion

// Namespace for the custom indicator
namespace MyCustomIndicator
{
/// <summary>
/// Donchian Channels with Offset. This version uses the highest high and the lowest low over a period    of time, with an optional offset.
/// </summary>
public class DonchianChannelsWithOffset : Indicator
{
    private MAX max;  // To calculate the highest high
    private MIN min;  // To calculate the lowest low

    [Range(-100, 100), NinjaScriptProperty]
    [Display(Name="Offset", Order=1, GroupName="Parameters")]
    public int Offset { get; set; } // Offset for shifting the channels

    protected override void OnStateChange()
    {
        // State.SetDefaults handles the initialization of the indicator's default settings.
        if (State == State.SetDefaults)
        {
            Description                 = "Donchian Channels with Offset";
            Name                        = "Donchian Channels with Offset";
            IsOverlay                   = true;
            IsSuspendedWhileInactive    = true;
            Period                      = 20; // Default lookback period of 20

            AddPlot(Brushes.Goldenrod, "Mean"); // Midline plot
            AddPlot(Brushes.DodgerBlue, "Upper"); // Upper plot
            AddPlot(Brushes.DodgerBlue, "Lower"); // Lower plot
        }
        else if (State == State.DataLoaded)
        {
            // Once data is loaded, initialize the MAX and MIN indicators
            max = MAX(High, Period);
            min = MIN(Low, Period);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnBarUpdate()
    {
        // Ensure enough bars have loaded
        if (CurrentBar < Period)
            return;

        // Calculate the upper, lower, and midline
        double upperVal = max[0];
        double lowerVal = min[0];
        double midlineVal = (upperVal + lowerVal) / 2;

        // Apply the offset, shifting the values by 'Offset' bars
        if (Offset != 0)
        {
            int shiftedBar = Math.Max(0, CurrentBar - Offset);
            Values[1][0] = max[shiftedBar];  // Upper channel
            Values[2][0] = min[shiftedBar];  // Lower channel
            Values[0][0] = (Values[1][0] + Values[2][0]) / 2; // Mean (midline)
        }
        else
        {
            Values[1][0] = upperVal;  // Upper channel
            Values[2][0] = lowerVal;  // Lower channel
            Values[0][0] = midlineVal;  // Mean (midline)
        }
    }

    #region Properties

    [Browsable(false)]
    [XmlIgnore()]
    public Series<double> Upper
    {
        get { return Values[1]; }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [XmlIgnore()]
    public Series<double> Lower
    {
        get { return Values[2]; }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    [XmlIgnore()]
    public Series<double> Mean
    {
        get { return Values[0]; }
    }

    [Range(1, int.MaxValue), NinjaScriptProperty]
    [Display(Name="Period", Order=2, GroupName="Parameters")]
    public int Period { get; set; }

    #endregion
     }
 }

 #region NinjaScript generated code. Neither change nor remove.

 namespace MyCustomIndicator
{
public partial class Indicator : NinjaTrader.Gui.NinjaScript.IndicatorRenderBase
{
    private DonchianChannelsWithOffset[] cacheDonchianChannelsWithOffset;
    public DonchianChannelsWithOffset DonchianChannelsWithOffset(int period, int offset)
    {
        return DonchianChannelsWithOffset(Input, period, offset);
    }

    public DonchianChannelsWithOffset DonchianChannelsWithOffset(ISeries<double> input, int period, int offset)
    {
        if (cacheDonchianChannelsWithOffset != null)
            for (int idx = 0; idx < cacheDonchianChannelsWithOffset.Length; idx++)
                if (cacheDonchianChannelsWithOffset[idx] != null &&  
 cacheDonchianChannelsWithOffset[idx].Period == period && cacheDonchianChannelsWithOffset[idx].Offset 
== offset && cacheDonchianChannelsWithOffset[idx].EqualsInput(input))
                    return cacheDonchianChannelsWithOffset[idx];
        return CacheIndicator<DonchianChannelsWithOffset>(new DonchianChannelsWithOffset() { Period =  
 period, Offset = offset }, input, ref cacheDonchianChannelsWithOffset);
    }
}
}

#endregion

So why it shows that code and also shows namespace is not valid.
I want someone who can fix this code from errors so i can run this code and see how it works.

I almost always use the built in Ninjascript editor unless actively debugging an issue.  The code below will compile as an indicator.  The lines marked <Modified> are the only lines I changed/added.
BTW... Your original code is very similar to the Ninjatrader built in DonchainChannel indicator.

